# Enviar correo con peso de 10M con librería System.Net.Mail de c# Window form

Tags: c#, windows-forms, net, mail

Estoy trabajando con la librería System.Net.Mail; de c#, para mandar correos en estos correos tengo que mandar un concentrado de estado de cuenta que Comprimo en Zip en c#. los correos se mandan correctamente cuando el archivo no Pesa mas de 2 MegasBytes, pero necesito mandar un Archivo zip de alrededor de 10 Megabytes. al enviarlo no tengo problema. pero el correo nunca me llega:

```
public void sendMail(string destino, string asunto, string coppyTo, string cuerpo, string from,string alias,string usuario,string password,string[] lista, string host)
    {
        MailMessage mmsg = new MailMessage();
        //para quien va diregido
        string[] correos = destino.Split(';') as string[];
        for (int i = 0; i < correos.Length; i++)
        {
            if (correos[i] != "")
            {
                mmsg.To.Add(correos[i]);

            }
        }
        //asunto del correo
        mmsg.Subject = asunto;
        //condear a utf8 por protocolos
        mmsg.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        //copiar a 
        //mmsg.Bcc.Add(coppyTo);
        mmsg.Body = cuerpo;
        mmsg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        //decirle que lo que biene en el cuerpo del correo es html;
        mmsg.IsBodyHtml = false;

        //correo de donde se envia
        mmsg.From = new MailAddress(from, alias);

        if (lista.Length > 0)
        {
            for(int x=0;x<lista.Length;x++)
            {
                if (lista[x]!="")
                {
                    Attachment data = new Attachment(lista[x], MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
                    mmsg.Attachments.Add(data);
                }
            }
        }
        mmsg.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

        //servidor de correo
        SmtpClient cliente = new SmtpClient();
        cliente.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usuario, password);
        cliente.Port = 587;
        cliente.EnableSsl = true;
        cliente.Timeout = 10000;
        cliente.Host = host;

        try
        {
            cliente.Send(mmsg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: esto va a depender mas que todo de tu proovedor ya que para gmail son 25mb pero para outlook son 10mb y asi va variando de proovedor a proovedor

Comment: El detalle es que cuando mando el correo desde Outlook si envía y me llega, pero cuando lo hago desde mi programa es cuando no llega. y le doy salida con el mismo correo y dominio de correo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema era Timeout lo tenia en 10000 como el archivo era muy grande no termina de salir, lo cambien a 60000, y  ya va todo bien.